# Using [] rather than a function call in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

In class we are asked to write a part of a code to make something the teacher wrote work. The problem is, I don't recognize the syntax. I asked a friend who said it may be an overloaded operator, but I just have no idea where to go with this.

```
    templateClass < int > obj(array, arrayS);                   

    cout << obj[1] << endl;
```

So it seems it should output the slot 1 of the array obj will be holding, but as I said, I've never seen this used before without ( ) and parameters.

Is this overloading the [ ] operator? How is it applying to the whole object?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to implement, i.e. write, overloaded `[]` operator that probably takes `size_t idx` as an argument. Also there is no *slot* term in C++, and it has other special meanings in toolkits like Qt.

Answer (score 3):

`templateClass < int > obj(array, arrayS);` is the same sort of syntax as `int obj(5);`.

It means we are declaring an object `obj`. The type is `templateClass<int>`, and the initializers are `array` and `arrayS`, which will end up as arguments to the class's constructor.

`obj[1]` means to invoke overloaded `operator[]` on `obj`. To see what this actually does, you will need to look up the class definition of `templateClass`.  (Or if you are supposed to make `obj[1]` work, you will need to write an overloaded `operator[]` in the class definition of `templateClass`).

Answer (score 0):

Take for example the following class

```
template <typename T>
class SimpleArray {
public:
    SimpleArray(const T& first_in = T(), const T& second_in = T()) :
        first(first_in), second(second_in) { }

    T& get(int index) {
        return (index == 0) ? (first) : (second);
    }

private:
    T first;
    T second;
};
```

and suppose in main you have

```
int main() {
    SimpleArray<int> simple(1,2);
    cout << simple.get(0) << ' ' << simple.get(1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So this is simply creating an object of type 'SimpleArray' with `T` as an `int` (passing 1 and 2 as the arguments to its constructor. Then you simply make `get()` calls to return the element asked for with the help of a simple ternary operator. Now you can overload the `[]` operator as so

```
template <typename T>
class SimpleArray {
public:
    SimpleArray(const T& first_in = T(), const T& second_in = T()) :
        first(first_in), second(second_in) { }

    T& get(int index) {
        return (index == 0) ? (first) : (second);
    }

    T& operator[] (int index) {
        return this->get(index);
    }

private:
    T first;
    T second;
};
```

and test it in main

```
int main() {
    SimpleArray<int> simple(1,2);
    cout << simple.get(0) << ' ' << simple.get(1) << endl;
    cout << simple[0] << ' ' << simple[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Again in this you simply call the `get()` function every time you access an element of the array using the `[]` syntax

Answer (score 0):

I read the assignment like this:

Write a template class that will accept these lines:

```
templateClass < int > obj(array, arrayS);
cout << obj[1] << endl;
```

The first line is a constructor taking to arguments and with int as template type and the second line is the [] operator.

But there is no specific requirements for the functionality of the template. In other words you can use your imagination and implement whatever you like as long as the constructor takes two arguments (and template type int) and the template class provides the [] operator.

Looking at the variable names (array, arrayS) it seems that the teacher wants you to pass an array and the size of the array. So one idea for a templateClass could be a class that took a c-style array as input and stored the values in to some c++ container.

That could be done like this:

```
template <typename T>
class templateClass {
public:
    // Constructor taking array T[] and size as arguments (first requirement)
    templateClass(const T d[], const size_t size)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            // Copy data from c-style array to a c++ vector 
            mData.push_back(d[i]);
        }
    }

    // [] operator (second requirement)
    T& operator[] (int index)
    {
        if ((index >= mData.size()) || (index < 0))
        {
            // Error - out of range
            // You could throw an exception here or some other error handling
            throw std::invalid_argument( "Invalid index" );
        }
        return mData[index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> mData;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int arr[3] = {5, 4, 9};
        templateClass < int > obj(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

        cout << obj[0] << endl;
        cout << obj[1] << endl;
        cout << obj[2] << endl;

        // Invalid index - will throw exception
        cout << obj[3] << endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Exception....";
    }

    return 0;
}
```